# T-SQL join with isnumeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database which looks like this: (well almost ;P)

**TABLE1**:

```
COL1 int (pk)
COL2 bit
COL3 int (FK to TABLE2 COL4)
```

**TABLE2**:

```
COL4 int (pk)
COL5 varchar(50)
```

Depending on the bit value the data contained in TABLE 2 will be numeric or not (1 is numeric).

If I run this query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(COL5 AS INT) 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
INNER JOIN 
    TABLE2 ON COL4 = COL3 AND COL2 = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(COL5)
```

I get a conversion failure error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '£0.00' to data type int

The query, without the cast, does not return this value, although the '£0.00' is in the table.

I was under the impression that the ON condition would be completed before the cast or am I wrong (obviously)?

Edit:

Running:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COL5 LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN -1 
            WHEN CAST(COL5 as bigint) > 2147483647 THEN -1 
            ELSE cast(COL5 as int) END
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 
    ON COL4 = COL3 AND COL2 = 1
```

executes and returns no `-1` values

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is an issue with `ISNUMERIC()`

Things like:  `'$0.00', '£0.00', '1e10'`
will all report as numeric, but you wont be able to convert them to `INT` or `DECIMAL`

Instead try this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(COL5 as money) as int) 
FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON COL4 = COL3 AND COL2 = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(COL5)
```

I have a blog article about the issues with `ISNUMERIC()`:
http://www.thatcoderguy.co.uk/2014/04/07/the-problem-with-isnumeric/

Comment: Nice explanation on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions in the `SELECT` part have nothing to do with those in the `JOIN`s, so the fact that you cast them on the select will not affect in any way the join expression. You're correct, however, when saying that the `ON` thing completes *before* the `SELECT` list.

Since both col5 invocations are different and unrelated, you must repeat the cast:

```
SELECT cast(COL5 as int)
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON COL4 = COL3 AND
                     COL2 = 1 AND
                     ISNUMERIC(CAST(COL5 AS INT))
```